# Add double quotation on duplicated name

Tags: awk, sed, grep

I want to find duplicated name from the file like below and marked them with "".

file:

```
James Miki:123-456-7890
Wang Tai:  234-563-6879
James Miki: 123-456-7890
```

Output wants to look like:

```
"James Miki": 123-456-7890
```

Thank you.

Comment: SO is not a free coding service. Please post what you have tried. Also, what happens to non-duplicated lines?

Comment: Are you up for using other standard UNIX programs like `sort` and `uniq`? Because they will make your life easier in a situation like this.

Comment: I typed sort databook2.txt | uniq -d, it prints out the unique name but how to add " " to the name in the databook2.txt

Comment: You just need to put quotes around the names in all lines of your output of sort|uniq? In that case your desired output seems correct. Otherwise, as @Mad Physicist has hinted, what do you want to happen to the non-duplicated lines? I additionally want to know, wether the whole line is guaranteed to be identical, or just the name, followed by possible differnt digits? Please add your experiment and itsd result to the question.

Comment: @MadPhysicist no they won't. try it.

Comment: @EdMorton. `uniq -c` will help because you can filter with `grep` for all lines with count > 1, then pipe through `sed` to get the original line with quotes back.

Comment: That's not helping at all. You end up with a chain of multiple commands when one small, trivial command will do (see http://stackoverflow.com/a/43264606/1745001). Honestly - try writing the command line you describe and compare it to @karakfa's answer to see if going that route helped. Obviously I'm not saying you can't do it that way, I'm just saying it's not helpful vs just using awk alone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this -

```
cat f
James Miki:123-456-7890
Wang Tai: 234-563-6879
James Miki: 123-456-7890
James Miki: 456-456-8888     ### added for test case
Wang Tai: 234-563-6879       ### added for test case
Vipin Kumar : 878-432-2345   ### added for test case
Vipin Kumar : 878-432-2345   ### added for test case

awk -F':' '{gsub(/ /,"",$2)}{b[$1FS$2]++} END {for(k in b) if(b[k]>1) {split(k,u,":"); print v,u[1],v FS u[2]}}' v='"' OFS=""  f
"Vipin Kumar ":878-432-2345
"Wang Tai":234-563-6879
"James Miki":123-456-7890
```

Explained -

```
gsub(/ /,"",$2): Remove space from 2nd column
b[$1FS$2]++    : Create array b and store col1 and 2 
if(b[k]>1)     : Check duplicate record
split(k,u,":") : split the stored value in k (combination of col1 and 2) so that we can add double quote on first column.
```

Comment: Hi VIPIN, thanks for your help. I tried your scripts but it seems like it only prints out one result from my test file, actually there are three duplicated name there.

Comment: @XimengZhao - I have updated My Answer with test cases and new code, please check.

Answer (score 1):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
$ awk -F: 'a[$1]++ {print "\"" $1 "\"" FS $2}' file

"James Miki": 123-456-7890
```

Comment: Hi, here's the result I get from the above code. what I want to show is to only label duplicated name and non-duplicated name is still there. Thanks.       "Evich Karen":284-758-2867
":
"Evich Karen":284-758-2867
":
":
"Fardbarkle Fred":674-843-1385
":
"":
":
"":
":
":
":
"":
"":
":
":
":
"Neal Jesse":408-233-8971
":
"":
"":
":
"":
":
":

Comment: please don't paste formatted data in comments but update your question instead.

Comment: @XimengZhao It's not possible to get output containing `Fardbarkle Fred` from input that did not contain `Fardbarkle Fred` unless you're explicitly printing `Fardbarkle Fred`, which I assume you aren't. When editing your question to explain the issue you're having with this solution (which is exactly the right solution to the question you asked) make sure the output you post matches your input and that both are truly representative of your real data.

Comment: Hi Ed, the question I posted here is a sample question. The data is very big and there are three duplicated name there. all these duplicated name are different from what I posted here. The idea is to add a label indicating duplicate names in the file. You can either add double quotation or anything else

Comment: @karakfa what does FS mean in your script?

Comment: it's the field separator set by `-F`, here `:`

Answer (score 0):

```
sed 's/: */:/' FILE | awk -F: '{ if (arr[$1":"$2]) print "\""$1"\":"$2; else { arr[$1":"$2]++; print $0 }}'
```

Comment: Thanks Ricardo, I tried out your script and found if there are two duplicated name in the file, it only printed out one with double quotation mark. And how to modify your code when your if condition is true, print all information.

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative using `sed` + `sort` + `uniq` pipeline:

```
cat file | sed 's/^\(.*\) *: */"\1": /' | sort | uniq -d
```

The output:

```
"James Miki": 123-456-7890
```

Comment: I got something like "James Miki: 123-456-7890", but I want is "James Miki": 123-456-7890, the double quotation mark is not with name.

Comment: @XimengZhao, check your expression for errors. The above approach works fine on your input