# Add a label indicating duplicate names

Tags: sed, text-processing

I tried to use

```
sed 's/ */:/' file | awk -F: '{ if (arr[$1":"$2]) print "\""$1"\":"$2; else { arr[$1":"$2]++; print $0 }}'
```

but cannot get ideal output. Thanks.

The following is the file information and the desired output that I want.

Text File:

```
Jon DeLoach:408-253-3122:123 Park St., San Jose, CA 04086:7/25/53:85100
Karen Evich:284-758-2857:23 Edgecliff Place, Lincoln, NB 92086:7/25/53:85100
Karen Evich:284-758-2867:23 Edgecliff Place, Lincoln, NB 92743:11/3/35:58200
Karen Evich:284-758-2867:23 Edgecliff Place, Lincoln, NB 92743:11/3/35:58200
Fred Fardbarkle:674-843-1385:20 Parak Lane, DeLuth, MN 23850:4/12/23:780900
Fred Fardbarkle:674-843-1385:20 Parak Lane, DeLuth, MN 23850:4/12/23:780900
Lori Gortz:327-832-5728:3465 Mirlo Street, Peabody, MA 34756:10/2/65:35200
Paco Gutierrez:835-365-1284:454 Easy Street, Decatur, IL 75732:2/28/53:123500
Paco Gutierrez:835-365-1284:454 Easy Street, Decatur, IL 75732:2/28/53:123500
Jesse Neal:408-233-8971:45 Rose Terrace, San Francisco, CA 92303:2/3/36:25000
Jesse Neal:408-233-8971:45 Rose Terrace, San Francisco, CA 92303:2/3/36:25000
Zippy Pinhead:834-823-8319:2356 Bizarro Ave., Farmount, IL 84357:1/1/67:89500
```

Required output: Add stars indicating duplicated names

```
Jon DeLoach:408-253-3122:123 Park St., San Jose, CA 04086:7/25/53:85100
*Karen Evich*:284-758-2857:23 Edgecliff Place, Lincoln, NB 92086:7/25/53:85100
*Karen Evich*:284-758-2867:23 Edgecliff Place, Lincoln, NB 92743:11/3/35:58200
*Karen Evich*:284-758-2867:23 Edgecliff Place, Lincoln, NB 92743:11/3/35:58200
*Fred Fardbarkle*:674-843-1385:20 Parak Lane, DeLuth, MN 23850:4/12/23:780900
*Fred Fardbarkle*:674-843-1385:20 Parak Lane, DeLuth, MN 23850:4/12/23:780900
Lori Gortz:327-832-5728:3465 Mirlo Street, Peabody, MA 34756:10/2/65:35200
*Paco Gutierrez*:835-365-1284:454 Easy Street, Decatur, IL 75732:2/28/53:123500
*Paco Gutierrez*:835-365-1284:454 Easy Street, Decatur, IL 75732:2/28/53:123500
*Jesse Neal*:408-233-8971:45 Rose Terrace, San Francisco, CA 92303:2/3/36:25000
*Jesse Neal*:408-233-8971:45 Rose Terrace, San Francisco, CA 92303:2/3/36:25000
Zippy Pinhead:834-823-8319:2356 Bizarro Ave., Farmount, IL 84357:1/1/67:89500
```

Comment: the continuance of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43264220/add-double-quotation-on-duplicated-name/43266276#43266276 ?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest  Yes, I post my raw data here just want to make the question more clear.

Comment: To make a question more clear, modify the question, don't post a whole new question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give a test to this. Seems to work ok.

```
$ awk -F":" 'NR==FNR{a[$1]++;next}(a[$1]>1){sub($1,"*" $1 "*")}1' file1 file1
```

Explanation:
This code reads the same file twice. This maybe has a performance penalty depending on the filesize.

`-F":"` : Global Input Fields Delimiter is defined as `:`
`NR==FNR{a[$1]++;next}` : The code in `{ }` is executed when `NR==FNR` = the first file is read by awk

`a[$1]++` : Creates an array `a` with index `$1` and value `++` => +1 for each $1 found. So for record 1 we have `a[Jon DeLoach]=1`. For Record2 `a[Karen Evich]=1`, for record 3 `a[Karen Evich]++` => `2`,etc

`next` : instructs awk to go to the next record and skip the rest script.

`(a[$1]>1){sub($1,"*" $1 "*")}1` : This condition & action is performed on the second file. For each `a[$1]` found in second file with a value `>1` (as has been finalized when the first file finished), we insert `*` around `$1` using awk sub function. `sub` function applies substitution directly to `$0` = Whole record.

`1` : prints the whole record of the second file.

Comment: Thanks it's right. Can you explain a little bit of your scripts, 'NR==FNR{a[$1]++;next}(a[$1]>1){sub($1,"*" $1 "*")}1' ?

Comment: @XimengZhao See update

Comment: nice explanation, great work

Comment: Is there anyway that can merge or delete duplicated result? I can use this command to delete duplicated result but not merge. awk '!seen[$0]++'

Comment: @XimengZhao What you mean by merge? Your command (`!seen[$0]++`) will print all uniq lines + one line of the duplicated lines. If you want to print only uniq lines exluding all duplicates you can try `awk -F":" 'NR==FNR{a[$1]++;next}a[$1]==1' file1 file1`